# Public synonyms issue with two schemas on same instance

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-mvc, oracle11g, oracle-xe

The database I am using is Oracle 11g Express Edition release 2.

I created 2 `schemas` in the same instance **xe**. They all have the same tables names and sequences names and stored procedures and stored functions and views names. But the tables `structures` and views `texts` are **different** ( there is some modifications between them ).

The reason for the creation of these two `schemas` is because our project has two **versions**. So the first `schema` is used for the first version , and the second `schema` was created for the second version. The mechanism of our web application `Spring` project is that whenever a connection is made through the web application login page then a corresponding Oracle user is making a connection according to the login entered ; so there is no fixed credential connection , there are Oracle users corresponding to each web application login.

So in order for each user to work with each database objects then I created `public synonyms` for every objects , and granted permissions to them for each user. But the database objects are owned by the `schema` I mentioned at the beginning. Now my problem is this : our customer wants the two project versions to be run on a same instance ( same computer server ). So one of the project version cannot run because the `public synonyms` can only refer to a particular `schema` owner. So how to make the `public synonyms` work for each `schema` ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. However, you can always use a distinct synonym name to identify the object.

Something similar to below:

```
create public synonym structures_v1 for schema1.structures;
create public synonym structures_v2 for schema2.structures;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides 2 totally different technologies for this situation (which comes to my mind):

- Editions (and Edition Based Redefinition)
- PDBs

With Editions you can create the same Object once in each Edition - but there are limitations like tables are not editionable. 
It's not a feature you just enable, you need to understand the concept and implement it properly.
PDBs enable consolidation of Databases with colliding namespace (such as your described synonyms) within the same CDB and therefore save SGA/memory. Basically they are totally separated - limited interference can be implemented when it's concept of object & data inheritance is understand.

Comment: what is the definition of PDB and CDB ?

Comment: Database containerisation is a chargeable extra to the 12c Enterprise Edition. The questioner clearly says they are using XE, so this part of the discussion is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a 3rd Schema and having Synonym and permission to query 1st and 2nd schema. Anyone tested this concept?